# How do I get the Vector skin to work on Mediawiki with Heroku?

Tags: php, heroku, mediawiki

I am following this guide https://dzone.com/articles/how-setup-free-mediawiki

My version numbers are:

- PHP 5.5.12
- Mediawiki 1.25.2 (downloaded using 
  https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Download_from_Git)
  When I view the wiki I get

  > Whoops! The default skin for your wiki, defined in $wgDefaultSkin as
  >   vector, is not available.
  >
  > You have no installed skins.

In my '/skins/ directory I have the Vector directory and in that is Vector.php. I have used the following code

```
$wgDefaultSkin = "vector";
wfLoadSkin( 'Vector' );
$wgVectorUseSimpleSearch = true;
$wgVectorUseIconWatch = true;
```

In my log file I get the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message '/app/skins/Vector/skin.json does not exist!' in /app/includes/registration/ExtensionRegistry.php:101
Stack trace:
/app/includes/GlobalFunctions.php(218): ExtensionRegistry->queue('/app/skins/Vect...')
/app/LocalSettings.php(139): wfLoadSkin('Vector')
/app/includes/WebStart.php(123): require_once('/app/LocalSetti...')
/app/index.php(38): require('/app/includes/W...')
{main}
thrown in /app/includes/registration/ExtensionRegistry.php on line 101
```

Sadly I'm not much of a PHP developer. We are all newbies at something! The error messages aren't great. I've done the obvious. '/skins/Vector' exists and has lots of files in it that look associated with a skin. The file '/skins/Vector/skin.json' exists. In the error message it is talking about '/app/skins...' and I don't know what this 'app' is. I suspect it is either PHP thing, a media wiki thing or a Heroku thing.

I'd appreciate some advice on what is wrong, or failing that 'how to troubleshoot it'.

Thank you all for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the skin directory is misconfigured. Try setting [$wgStyleDirectory](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgStyleDirectory) explicitly.

Comment: Thanks. I will try that tomorrow and let you know how it works.

Comment: Did it help? I have the same problem. I'm on the mediawiki REL1_26 (github) branch and tried a git pull of the skins directory. Same error. Then I cloned https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki-skins-Vector and switched to REL1_26 branch directly into skins. I physically see the skin.json file but got the same error

Comment: I had never set ```$wgStyleDirectory``` explicitly but got the same error when I upgraded to the REL1_26 branch via Git. According to the error message, ```skins/Vector/skin.json``` was missing - and indeed it was, but ```skins/vector/skin.json``` was there. Notice the lowercase ```vector```. A symlink helped in my case. I don't know where the uppercase ```Vector``` comes from, as I have ```require_once("skins/vector/Vector.php");``` set.

Comment: `skins/vector` was at a time part of MediaWiki core, loaded via [skin autodiscovery](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Skin_autodiscovery). It was deprecated in 1.23 and removed in 1.25, in favor of explicitly requiring skins the same way it is done for extensions.